# sheetjs alternative with styling

Tags: node.js, sheetjs

My question is about parsing & styling excel sheets in node.js. I see that `sheetJS` offers styling with excelsheet in Node.js with a [PRO version.](https://sheetjs.com/pro/)

Is there any alternative to this module which allows styling like aligning text to middle in a cell, or creating borders in cell columns, or many more styling that can be useful ?

Indeed if there is not alternative, is it really that users need to pay to use styling in excelsheet, apparently these devs built this module to make a profit, and the key values to style are not even similar to CSS names which cause confusion.

So is paying for PRO the only option in Node.js ? Is there any module that comes with all the futures ?